# Why does cp not respect ACLs?

Tags: linux, access-control-list

A common way to set up a directory for file sharing within a group, is:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ chgrp felles foo
$ chmod g+ws foo
$ setfacl -m group:felles:rwx foo
$ setfacl -dm group:felles:rwx foo
```

This ensures that any files created in `foo` is readable and writable by the group `felles`:

```
$ umask
0022
$ echo hi > foo/bar
$ ls -l foo
total 4
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 bhm felles 3 2010-09-23 00:18 bar
```

However, if you copy a file into `foo`, the default ACLs are not applied:

```
$ echo you > baz
$ cp baz foo/
$ ls -l foo
total 8
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 bhm felles 3 2010-09-23 00:18 bar
-rw-r--r--+ 1 bhm felles 4 2010-09-23 00:19 baz
$ getfacl foo/baz
# file: foo/baz
# owner: bhm
# group: felles
user::rw-
group::rwx          #effective:r--
group:felles:rwx        #effective:r--
mask::r--
other::r--
```

Why does this happen, and is there a way around it?

(*Moving* a file into the directory does not respect either ACLs or group ownership, but I can understand why: you might not want the permissions of a file to change simply because you change its name.)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/452678/46333 this answer contains a good explanation.

Answer (score 12):

If `cp` creates the destination file, it replicates the permissions of the source file, except for the bits that are set in the umask. This is standard behavior (see e.g. step 3.b in the [Single Unix v3 (POSIX 2001) specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/cp.html).

Why was cp designed this way? Because there are many cases where this behavior is desirable, for example preserving a file's privacy when the original permissions are restrictive, and preserving executability is almost always the right thing to do. It is however unfortunate that not even GNU cp has an option to turn this behavior off.

Most copy tools (e.g. pax, rsync) behave in the same way. You can ensure the file will be created with the default permission by decoupling the source from the destination, for example with `cat <baz >foo/baz`.

Comment: Well, that at least explains the motivation for it.  (Strange, though, that the group ownership is allowed to change to "felles", giving potentially more people read access to the file.)

Comment: I would like to point out that the problem is real. Can you help us solve it? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/711319

Answer (score 5):

Well, a three-year old and more question but still relevant. For future readers, I want to add that it is expected that mv, cp commands do not follow destination directory's ACL. Gilles's answer is all fine but the last sentence. The better way to apply the destination's ACL to the copied/moved file is the way mentioned here:

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4281/copy-acl-of-one-file-to-another-using-getfacl-and-setfacl

In case the link is broken in future, I paste the content here:

```
getfacl <file-with-acl> | setfacl -f - <file-with-no-acl>
```

copy ACL of one file to another using getfacl and setfacl

**WARNING: Existing ACL will get lost.**

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `-p` or `--preserve` with `cp`.

From `man 5 acl`:

> CHANGES TO THE FILE UTILITIES
>
> ```
>  On a system that supports ACLs, the file utilities ls(1), cp(1), and
>  mv(1) change their behavior in the following way:
>
>  ·   For files that have a default ACL or an access ACL that contains more
>      than the three required ACL entries, the ls(1) utility in the long
>      form produced by ls -l displays a plus sign (+) after the permission
>      string.
>
>  ·   If the -p flag is specified, the cp(1) utility also preserves ACLs.
>      If this is not possible, a warning is produced.
>
>  ·     The mv(1) utility always preserves ACLs. If this is not possible, a
>      warning is produced.
>
>  The effect of the chmod(1) utility, and of the chmod(2) system call, on
>  the access ACL is described in CORRESPONDENCE BETWEEN ACL ENTRIES AND
>  FILE PERMISSION BITS.
> ```

Comment: Not exactly. He wants the file to have the same permission as the target folder.

Comment: This answer should not have any thumbs up. The OP was not asking how to make the `cp` command preserve a files permissions. The OP was asking why ACLs are not applied to the copy of the file that the `cp` command made.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with rsynced files lacking the proper default ACLs in the target subdirectory.  Cp does not have a way of setting the permissions on the target.  But, rsync does, using the `--chmod=ugo=rwx` flag.  See my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/455111/rsynced-files-not-getting-proper-acl/455217#455217).

Answer (score 0):

The ACLs are propagating correctly, but the default mask doesn't seem to be correct. You probably want your default mask to be rwX.

```
setfacl -dm m::rwX foo
```

If that doesn't work, please post the ACL for foo.

Comment: That did not work.  The ACL for foo (both prior and after your command) is# file: foo
# owner: bhm
# group: felles
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:felles:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:felles:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

Answer (score -1):

From what I see you are the owner of the files (bhm) before and after the cp. As the directory listing shows the owner has read and write access!

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear: I want the _group_ ("felles") to be able to (read and) write the file.